How can I solve the red status bar "launching debugger" error?
I'm using Qt 5.15.0 with Qt Creator 14.0.2 on Windows.
When I try to run the debugger (GNU gdb 8.1 for MinGW 8.1.0 32-64bit) with Qt 5.15.0, I always get a red status bar saying "launching debugger".
To fix it, I tried to change Qt versions, but the error remained.
Do I have to configure the debugger?
Build & run command doesn't produce any errors, and the .exe works correctly, but when I use debug mode start command, it fails when launching the debugger.
In the compiler output, I have:
09:37:21: Running steps for project XL3DriverInterface...

09:37:21: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.

09:37:21: Starting: "C:\Qt_V1\Tools\mingw810_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" -j8

C:/Qt_V1/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug

mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/SW_Progetti/XL3Driver_Interface/build/Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'

mingw32-make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.

mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/SW_Progetti/XL3Driver_Interface/build/Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'

09:37:23: The process "C:\Qt_V1\Tools\mingw810_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.

09:37:23: Elapsed time: 00:02.

Here's my configuration:
Kits list:

Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug kit configuration, which uses MinGW 8.1.0 64-bit:

Compilers list:

Debuggers list:

General debugger configuration:


Is there no debugger log you can show of the problem?

To add to the above comment: see Qt Creator Documentation — Debugger Log.

I have no file log. In Application Output i have: 08:46:53: Debugging C:\SW_Progetti\XL3Driver_Interface\build\Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\XL3DriverInterface.exe ...
08:46:54: Debugging of C:\SW_Progetti\XL3Driver_Interface\build\Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\XL3DriverInterface.exe has finished.
